# When implementing based on Drupal 9 ResourceBase, dependency injection resolution seems to fail

Tags: drupal

I want to write a RestResource based on ResourceBase.  Most of this is working ok, but I wanted to inject a service class to house db/repo logic; in order to do this, I attempted to overload the create // construct methods of ResourceBase, but when I apply the code from core/modules/rest/src/Plugin/ResourceBase.php :

```
 public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, array $serializer_formats, LoggerInterface $logger) {
parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
$this->serializerFormats = $serializer_formats;
$this->logger = $logger;}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest')
    );
  }
```

and then run cache-rebuild, with my module enabled, the logger.factory->rest seems to be returning a LoggerChannel instead of a LoggerInterface:

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Drupal\xxxxx\Plugin\rest\resource\xxxxx::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\xxxxx\Plugin\rest\resource\LoggerInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel given

what is the correct container / service reference for what is required here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point.  I re-examined what I had, and added the above using statement.  Also checked my services.yml to make sure I used the correct service resolution for the DI (xxx.repository), and had to cross-check all the namespaces

final version (with repo injection below):

```
namespace Drupal\xxx\Plugin\rest\resource;
use Drupal\xxx;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Provides Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "xxx_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("XXX Resource"),
 *   serialization_class = "",
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/xxx",
 *     "create" = "/xxx/callback"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class XXXResource extends ResourceBase {
  private \Drupal\XXX\Repository $repository;
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, array $serializer_formats, LoggerInterface $logger, \Drupal\XXX\Repository $repo) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition,$serializer_formats,$logger,$repo);
    $this->serializerFormats = $serializer_formats;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->repository=$repo;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'),
      $container->get('xxx.repository')
    );
  }

//add post/get / etc behaviors below, then enable via RestUI module
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably declaring `LoggerInterface`'s alias wrong.

Replace:

```php
use Drupal\xxxxx\Plugin\rest\resource\LoggerInterface
```

with:

```php
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
```